# Qt all the drawings disappear when I click anywhere outside the running program

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make something like network on Qt but while running the program I faced a weird error all the drawings disappear when I click anywhere outside the running program or open any other application.
[image: this is a pic of the running program at first]

[image: and this when I click anywhere outside the running program]

here is the code

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(210*6+10,this->height());

    Lobes["Frontal Lobe"] = {"Higher Mental \n function",
                            "Broca's area",
                            "Motor Function\n(Eye Movement)"};

    Lobes["Partial Lobe"] = {"Motor Function\n(Muscles)",
                             "Somatosensory \n association\narea",
                             "Sensory Area"};

    Lobes["Temporal Lobe"] = {"Association area",
                             "Auditory area",
                             "Wernicke's area"};

    Lobes["Occiptal Lobe"] = {"Visual area"};

SizeCalculations();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(Qt::red);


    it = Lobes.begin();
    int space = 10;
    for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {

        if(x < 6)
        {
            Node *Rec = new Node(CognitveSpace,50,CogitiveFunctions[x],0,szCogntive);

            painter.drawRect(Rec->getRectangle());
            painter.drawText(Rec->getRectangle(), Qt::AlignCenter, Rec->getName());
           // painter.fillRect(Rec->getRectangle(),Qt::red);
            CognitveSpace += szCogntive.width()+10;
        }
        if(x < 4)
        {
           Node *Rec = new Node(LobesSpace,250,it->first,0,szLobes);
           painter.drawRect(Rec->getRectangle());
           painter.drawText(Rec->getRectangle(), Qt::AlignCenter, Rec->getName());
          // delete Rec;

           for(size_t index = 0; index < it->second.size();index++)
           {

               Node *Rec = new Node(AreasSpace,450,it->second[index],0,szAreas);
               painter.drawRect(Rec->getRectangle());
               painter.drawText(Rec->getRectangle(), Qt::AlignCenter, Rec->getName());
               space += 180;
               //delete Rec;
               AreasSpace += szAreas.width()+10;
           }
           it++;
           LobesSpace += szLobes.width()+10;
           AreasSpace = LobesSpace +15;
        }

    }

}


void Widget::SizeCalculations()
{
    szCogntive.setWidth((this->width() / 6) - CognitveSpace);
    szLobes.setWidth((this->width() / 4) - LobesSpace);
    szAreas.setWidth(szLobes.width()/3 - 15);
}
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}
```

Comment: Code and similar goes *in* the question. *Not* behind external links (especially not broken ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple problem: the paint event should be, effectively, const. You're modifying various sizes repeatedly, on each repaint. But we can have the compiler help you out - let's modify the code to make your object invariant in painting:

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
  QPainter painter(this);
  paintEvent(event, painter);
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *, QPainter &painter) const { // const is important!
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(Qt::red);
    // etc - rest of the code follows
}

// Declaration in the class
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *, QPainter &) const; // const!!
```

Now compile - the compiler will flag as errors all the locations where you modify the object. You'll need to move those computations elsewhere, so that painting doesn't modify the object. Then it'll work.